# iPhone app crashes when trying to push detailed view because "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, crash

I'm having the following error, which is caused by the piece of code below:

**error**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

**code**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    newsDetailView *NieuwsDetailView = [[newsDetailView alloc] init];
    [NewsDetailView setAlleItems:newsItems];
    [NewsDetailView setCurrentItemId:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", newsItems);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:NewsDetailView animated:YES]; // This line gives the error
    [NewsDetailView release];
}
```

I have an UITableView with news items filled from an online XML feed. I'm parsing using XMLTouch. When I click an item to get to the detailed view, it crashes.

I've Googled the problem but I do count all the array items in the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}` method (return `[newsItems count];`).

Also I'm logging the complete newsItems array, right above the crash. And I can tell you, it's not empty.

So if it's not the number of rows, and not an empty array.. what is it?

One strange (?) thing:
I always get this error: "index **0** beyond bounds for empty array". Even if I clicked the third or fourth row, which would've given me an error like "index **3** beyond bounds for empty array" or something.. right?

** Additional info on detailed view .m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setTitle:@"News"];
}

- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

NSString *titel;
NSString *bericht;
NSString *datum;
NSString *foto;

titel = [[newsItems objectAtIndex: currentItemId] objectForKey: @"titel"];
bericht = [[newsItems objectAtIndex: currentItemId] objectForKey: @"bericht"];
datum = [[newsItems objectAtIndex: currentItemId] objectForKey: @"datum"];
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2) {
    foto = [[newsItems objectAtIndex: currentItemId] objectForKey: @"fotoRetina"];
} else {
    foto = [[newsItems objectAtIndex: currentItemId] objectForKey: @"foto"];
}

// Code I've ommited to keep things clear.
// I created a scrollView and put stuff in it, here. If anybody is interested in seeing this I can update this.

}

// No viewWillAppear, setAlleItems or setCurrentItemId methods
```

Comment: Are you sure is is exactly the code? I cannot see how `[self.navigationController NewsDetailView animated:YES];` should even be able to compile. Another hint: please use lowercase first letters for variables and uppercase first letters for classes. This makes it much easier for other people to read your code.

Comment: I guess the problem is NewsDetailView implementation. Also, the line you mark as problematic is not valid objective-c.

Comment: @madmw What's not valid about it?

Comment: as others said, this: [self.navigationController NewsDetailView animated:YES] is non sense; your code problem is more likely to be in property declaration and accessors implementations, not in the table view or even in the view controller

Comment: @madmw I think so too, I just don't know what..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT;

Add

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newsItems;
```

to your header and

```
@synthesize newsItems;
```

to your implementation file.

old answer:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:NewsDetailView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Erm, ok. Now I see what Tonklon and madmw were talking about too. I must have accidentally deleted pushViewController when posting this question. The line in Xcode looks actually like this:

[self.navigationController pushViewController:NewsDetailView animated:YES];

(like you said it has to be)

So unfortunately, that's not the answer..

Comment: Can you post the setAlleItems method and setCurrentItemId method?

Comment: and what does NSLog(@"%d", [newsItems count]); output?

Comment: Ok, so please post code of `newsDetailView`. We are interested in implementation of `setAlleItems:`, `setCurrentItemId:`, `loadView`, `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:`. Basically everything that is invoked before the view actually appears.

Comment: setAlleItems is an NSMutableArray and currentItemId is an integer. There's no further method but passing data between two views. [newsItems count] outputs 9.

Comment: I've added those methods (edited my question to keep things clear). I must say that I've used this code before and it worked fine then. I compared the codes and I don't see anything different.. I'm baffled..

Comment: Another strange (?) thing: when I log the output of '[newsItem count]' in the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath method' it works. But when I log it in  the 'numberOfRowsInSection method' it doesn't do anything.. The code does handle the method though. Because when I change it to a hardcoded 4 it shows me 4 items (instead of all (9)).

Comment: I now think you are using Automatic Reference Counting and that it is being released before you are finished with it. Can you show us where you alloc/init newsItems? I would make sure newsItems is a defined and synthesized as a property and not just created at runtime.

Comment: In viewDidAppear the app checks whether newsItems is set (if array is empty) if not it performs a 'grabRSSFeed: method' (and reloads the table after it. In that grabRSSFeed method I alloc it: 'newsItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];' parse the xml and add objects to it: '[newsItems addObject:[item copy]];'. newsItems is a parameter declared in the header: 'NSMutableArray *newsItems;'

Answer (score 0):

How you are initialing the nib file for the newsDetailView?

Since the nib file is not created or initiated, the index array out of bounds exception happens related to the view.

So try to create the nib file and push the view controller after that.

Because, without the nib file, the navigation controller has nothing to push on to the stack.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: I don't like working with Interface Builder so build everything programmatically.

Comment: when you are initializing the nib file? The code you posted does not initialize the nib.

Comment: Just to clarify, from the update you gave for your question, you have mentioned,   // No viewWillAppear, setAlleItems or setCurrentItemId methods  ......  Are they properties defined in newsDetalView.h file? If so, what are the property parameters you have defined for that? or  are you calling an api (setAlleItems, setCurrentItmeId) which is not defined in your newsDetailView view controller?

Comment: Yes, they are parameters defined in the header file. An NSMutableArray and an integer.

Comment: If they are parameters with retain property, you can use dot property to access the variable instead of your current format. Like,

newsDetailView.CurrentItemId = <value>;

Try this and verify your pushViewController, whether it is null or not.